# C++ Ambiguous template instantiation for nested variadic template classes

Tags: c++, templates, g++, variadic-templates, clang++

Consider the following:

```
template<class... T>
struct outer
{
  template<int... I>
  struct helper{};

  template<int Num, class = helper<>>
  struct inner;
  template<int Num, int... V>
  struct inner<Num,helper<V...>> : public inner<Num-1,helper<V...,sizeof...(V)>>{};
  template<int... V>
  struct inner<0, helper<V...>>{
    using type = helper<V...>;
  };
};

int main(){
  outer<int>::inner<7>::type i;
}
```

I've found this code will compile without errors using clang-9.0.1 but fails using gcc-9.2.0 with the following errors:

```
test2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct outer<int>::inner<1, outer<int>::helper<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5> >’:
test2.cpp:10:9:   recursively required from ‘struct outer<int>::inner<6, outer<int>::helper<0> >’
test2.cpp:10:9:   required from ‘struct outer<int>::inner<7>’
test2.cpp:18:22:   required from here
test2.cpp:10:9: error: ambiguous template instantiation for ‘struct outer<int>::inner<0, outer<int>::helper<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6> >’
   10 |  struct inner<Num,helper<V...>> : public inner<Num-1,helper<V...,sizeof...(V)>>{};
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.cpp:10:9: note: candidates are: ‘template<class ... T> template<int Num, int ...V> struct outer<T>::inner<Num, outer<T>::helper<V ...> > [with int Num = 0; int ...V = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; T = {int}]’
test2.cpp:12:9: note:                 ‘template<class ... T> template<int ...V> struct outer<T>::inner<0, outer<T>::helper<V ...> > [with int ...V = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; T = {int}]’
   12 |  struct inner<0, helper<V...>>{
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.cpp:10:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct outer<int>::inner<0, outer<int>::helper<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6> >’
   10 |  struct inner<Num,helper<V...>> : public inner<Num-1,helper<V...,sizeof...(V)>>{};
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.cpp:8:9: note: declaration of ‘struct outer<int>::inner<0, outer<int>::helper<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6> >’
    8 |  struct inner;
      |         ^~~~~
test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test2.cpp:18:24: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘outer<int>::inner<7>’
   18 |  outer<int>::inner<7>::type i;
      |
```

I've seen similar recursive inheritance succeed in gcc, but it seems not when it's inside of a variadic template class. Also of note is that changing the outer template to `template<class T>` fixes the gcc errors.

Is this a clang or gcc bug?

Comment: I would say g++ bug. `template<class... T>
struct outer` should not change something against working `template<class T>
struct outer`. `struct inner<0, helper<V...>` is clearly more specialized than struct `inner<Num, helper<V...>`...